# auto-mode-alist for python files

Tags: python, auto-mode-alist

Am doing the following for org files.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
```

What should I do for python ?

Comment: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))` but aren't both of these in `auto-mode-alist` by default?

Comment: With `emacs -q` (version 28.2) I find entries for both python and org: `("\\.py[iw]?\\'" . python-mode)` and `("\\.org\\'" . org-mode)`. You shouldn't have to do anything: when you open `foo.py` it should be in Python mode and when you open `foo.org` it should be in Org mode.